# Is it possible to invent a sorting algorithm for less than O(n)?

Tags: algorithms, computational-complexity, sorting, data-structure

Currently for a large randomly generated array of elements lets say array of int can be sorted within `O(n logn)`.  Is it possible to invent a sorting algorithm for `O(n)` or less than `O(n)`? What is the theoretical limit and how do we proof that limit?

Comment: See here for an explanation for the $O(n\log n)$: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/academic/class/15211/fall.97/www/recitations/rec1006

Comment: Spaghetti sort!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you cannot have a sorting algorithm that runs in less than $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time.  Suppose you want to sort a list of $n$ numbers. You must always look at all $n$ numbers, and this process itself runs in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time.

There are some $\mathcal{O}(n)$ sorting algorithms that exist, but they are not [comparison-based sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort), and they all assume some information about the numbers being processed (see, for example, [counting sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort), or [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)). It is has been proven that a comparison-based  sorting algorithm cannot run faster than $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ time.